# Derivative of a polynomial in a field $\mathbb{F}$ with $\operatorname{char}(\mathbb{F})=p>0$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Let $\mathbb{F}$ be a field with $\operatorname{char}(\mathbb{F})=p>0$.

The derivative of a polynomial  $P(x)={\displaystyle \sum\limits _{i=0}^{n}a_{i}x^{i}}\in\mathbb{F}[x]$ is $P'(x)=\sum\limits _{i=1}^{n}a_{i}ix^{i-1}\in\mathbb{F}[x]$.

I wish to prove that for $f\in\mathbb{F}[x]$:$f'=0\implies f(x)=g(x^p)$ where $g(x)\in\mathbb{F}[x]$.

I tried going by this definition of the derivative here but all I got was $p\mid ia_i$ for all $i=1,2,..,n$.

Any ideas ?

Comment: What does mean $p | i a_i$ ?

Comment: The following tangential comment might interest some readers. The error correction process for the Reed-Solomon codes used in CD and DVD players requires evaluation simultaneous evaluation of $\Lambda(x)$ and $x\Lambda^\prime(x)$ at the $255$-th roots of unity in $\mathbb F_{2^8}$ of characteristic $2$, and takes advantage of the fact that $x\Lambda^\prime(x)=\Lambda_1x+\Lambda_3x^3+\Lambda_5x^5+\cdots$ to save a lot of calculation by arranging the computation of $\Lambda(\alpha)$ to produce $\alpha\Lambda^\prime(\alpha)$ as a side result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** While technically correct, the notion of divides, i.e. $\mid\;$, is not the best way to phrase things here; instead, since $\operatorname{char}(F)=p$, what you have is $ia_i=0$ for all $i=1,2,\ldots,n$. What does that tell you?

Comment: $i=0$ or $a_i=0$ ?

Comment: Exactly! :) $\text{}$ But remember, $i$ is not an element of the field $\mathbb F$, but is just a positive integer, so $i=0$ really only tells you that...

Comment: With this hint I got that:$a_1=0,...a_{p-1}=0,a_{p+1}=0...$ hence $P(x)=a_px^p+a_{2p}x^{2p}+...$ right ? :)

Comment: Well, I should mention that for any $i\geq0$, either $a_i=0$ or $p\mid i$, *or both* - so it still might be the case that some of the $a_{np}=0$.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! by the way, can we say something about $x^p$ ? it's probably not true but does $x^p=x^0=1$ ? (why ?)

Comment: You're right, that's not true, since $x$ is a variable - it doesn't satisfy any relations. In fact, it isn't even true that for every element $a$ in a field of characteristic $p$, that $a^p=a$. A good way to remember that is that $a^p=a$ is the **defining property** of being an element of $\mathbb{F}_p$.

Comment: hmm..so $x^p$ is just a notation for $x*x*...x$ p times (and we consider $p\in\mathbb{N}$) ?

Comment: That's right. Well, that's what exponentiation means in general, not just for $x$ :) It just so happens that raising to a power divisible by $p$ can have unusual effects on elements of a field of characteristic $p$. But since $x$ is not an element of the field, just an "indeterminate", it acts normally.

Comment: "raising to a power divisible by p can have unusual effects on elements of a field " can you please say what do you mean ?

Comment: For elements of a finite field of size $p^n$, raising to the $p^n$th power doesn't do anything, i.e. $a^{p^n}=a$ for $a\in\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$. In fact, this is the defining property for elements of $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$. So for example, look at the field like the rational functions in $T$ over $\mathbb{F}_p$, which is written $\mathbb{F}_p(T)$. This is a field of characteristic $p$. In it, we have $a^p=a$ for $a\in \mathbb{F}_p\subset \mathbb{F}_p(T)$, but $T^p\neq T$. So raising to a power divisible by $p$ doesn't always act differently, only sometimes.

Answer (score 4):

The main point you have to understand here is that the statement   $p |ia_i $  doesn't make sense because $p$ is not in $F$ and also there is no reasonable definition of "divisibility" in a field.

The correct thing to say is that $ia_i=\bar i\cdot a_i\in F$, with $\bar i\in \mathbb F_p\subset F$.
Hence if $p$ does not divide $i$ **in $\mathbb N$** (where divisibility makes sense!), we have $\bar i\neq 0\in F$ and since $\bar i\cdot a_i=0\in F$ we deduce $a_i=0\in F$.
From this you get $f(x)=g(x^p)$ where $g(y)=\sum_i a_{ip}y^i$.

Comment: Well, I said that at first too, but $p=\underbrace{1+\cdots+1}_{p\text{ times}}$ still makes sense in $F$, and since $p=0$ in $F$ and $0\mid m$ implies $m=0$ in any ring, $p\mid ia_i$ is still saying that $ia_i=0$ in $F$. But of course, I agree that $\mid$ is not the right thing to use in this situation.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out, indeed it sould be written in a different way as you stated. +1

Comment: Zev note is a good point too as there is a reasonable definition for divisibility in any ring really.

Comment: Dear @Zev, if $1\in \mathbb N$ is the usual Peano integer and if $p=1+...+1\in \mathbb N$ then, no, $p=1+1+...+1$ is not in $F$ because $\mathbb N$ is in no sense included in $F$: for example $F$ might be finite and $\mathbb N$ is infinite. On the other hand it is true that $\bar p=p*1_F=1_F+...+1_F=0_F\in F$ where I have denoted by $*$ the scalar multiplication of an element of $\mathbb Z$ with an element of the $\mathbb Z$-algebra $F$. The sentence you use "p=0 in F" is an abuse of language short-circuiting these precise notations. (To be continued)

Comment: (Continued) This is  perfectly admissible  for people, like you, who know exactly what they mean but beginners should  be absolutely precise when confronted with  these subtle concepts for the first time.

Comment: Dear @Belgi, in a  formal sense it is true that there is a notion of divisibility in any ring: you can decree that $a$ divides $b$ if there exists $c$ with $b=ac$ . What I wrote in my answer is that this notion is not *reasonable*  in a field, where any non-zero element divides every element. It is also useless and even treacherous in rings with zero-divisors. Divisibility on the other hand is admirably suited for going back and forth between a UFD $R$ and its field of fractions $K$, especially when considering the polynomial rings $R[X]$ and $K[X]$ : think Gauss, Eisenstein,...